# What can be the reason for `clone()` returning a non-PID as reported by strace?

Tags: linux, pid, strace

I'm trying to track the creation of processes by analyzing the output of `strace` and after a couple of thousand lines I'm encountering a situation I've never seen before. In this short snippet you can see the first occurrence of `PID=501135`:

```
501133 1677685727.376373 clone(child_stack=0x7fbb38c77000, flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWPID|SIGCHLD) = 501134
501134 1677685727.377751 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/setgroups", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
501134 1677685727.377897 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/uid_map", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
501134 1677685727.377998 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/gid_map", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
501134 1677685727.378102 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mounts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
501134 1677685727.378926 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fbb38c78a10) = 2
501135 1677685727.380065 execve("/bin/true", ["/bin/true"], []) = 0
501135 1677685727.388634 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
501135 1677685727.388742 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
501135 1677685727.389288 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

As you can see `PID=501135` suddenly shows up and there is no `vfork`, `clone`, `clone3` or whatsoever indicating it's creation.

Also in the last line before the first occurrence there is a `clone()` returning `2` instead of a PID, so I suspect it to be the `clone` that *should* return `501135`.

I know there can be `unfinished ...` and `... resumed` lines which can temporarily hide creation of a PID until the according `... resumed` line shows up. I'm already taking care of this and `grep`ing through the complete log doesn't show `501135` anywhere but in the lines I've pasted.

What am I missing? Is there a chance to reliably trace every PID with `strace` (or an alternative, I don't know any..)

**Update**:

Thanks to @tkausl's hint regarding the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag I managed to solve lots of formerly failing PID lookups. I'm currently using the following approach:

- keep a mapping `pid_offset`: PID -> Initial PID
- update that map every time `CLONE_NEWPID` is among the `clone()` flags:

```
if "CLONE_NEWPID" in clone.flags:
    pid_offset[strace.result] = strace.pid
```

- every time `clone()` is executed with a PID with a mapping in `pid_offset` I re-calculate the "actual" PID from the result of `clone()` and the offset:

```
new_pid = strace.result_nr
if strace.pid in pid_offset:
    new_pid = strace.result + pid_offset[strace.pid]
    pid_offset[new_pid] = pid_offset[strace.pid]
```

strangely this works for the majority of cases, but not all. Here is a case I'm still stumbling upon (stripped down to relevant calls of `clone()`. The PID I have no trace for is `501376`:

```
# Here is a case which actually works: 
# PID 501133 creates 501134 with CLONE_NEWPID and as a result
# 501134 successfully creates 501135:
#
501133 1677685727.376373 clone(child_stack=0x7fbb38c77000, flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWPID|SIGCHLD) = 501134
+++ CLONE_NEWPID for clone() with PID=501133: 501133

501134 1677685727.378926 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fbb38c78a10) = 2
+++ clone_PID: 501134, new_PID = PID_offset=501133 + result=2 = 501135


# Now comes a long chain of `clone()` calls starting with
# 501149 cloning with CLONE_NEWPID, working in the beginning:
#
501149 1677685727.761916 clone(child_stack=0x7f24b72cc000, flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWUSER|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWNET|SIGCHLD) = 501150
+++ CLONE_NEWPID for clone() with PID=501149: 501149

501150 1677685727.776125 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f24b72cda10) = 2
+++ clone_PID: 501150, new_PID = PID_offset=501149 + result=2 = 501151
501151 1677685727.838544 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f0d7075aa10) = 3
+++ clone_PID: 501151, new_PID = PID_offset=501149 + result=3 = 501152

... here the PIDS 501152..501373 get created successfully

501161 1677685728.487811 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f28da126ad0) = 225
+++ clone_PID: 501161, new_PID = PID_offset=501149 + result=225 = 501374
501161 1677685728.488968 clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f28da126ad0) = 226
+++ clone_PID: 501161, new_PID = PID_offset=501149 + result=226 = 501375

501376 1677685728.489090 execve("/opt/bin/touch", [CMD..], [ENV...]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

So the last line shows PID=`501376` which I don't know where it get's created and how to calculate the value `501376`.

I suspect some off-by-one-error, but simply adding `+ 1` somewhere just leads to unknown PIDs at other places..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first line creates `501134` not `501135`

Comment: Right, misread that. Let me write an answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
As you can see PID=501135 suddenly shows up and there is no vfork, clone, clone3 or whatsoever indicating it's creation.

Also in the last line before the first occurrence there is a clone() returning 2 instead of a PID, so I suspect it to be the clone that should return 501135.
```

Its *kind* of correct, the second clone *does* create that PID but still correctly returns PID 2. Thats because your first clone creates a new PID namespace (`CLONE_NEWPID`) which takes the PID 1 **inside** the new namespace. The next clone *from within that namespace* gets PID 2 **inside** that namespace and gets the PID 501135 in the parent namespace.

Comment: So to reliably track PIDs I'd have to remember calls of `clone` with `CLONE_NEWPID` set and be prepared for `old_pid + new_pid - 1` to show up? Or is there another way to get the parent process ID of a given PID from just the `strace` output?

Comment: `So to reliably track PIDs I'd have to remember calls of clone with CLONE_NEWPID set and be prepared for old_pid + new_pid - 1 to show up?` pretty much. `Or is there another way to get the parent process ID of a given PID from just the strace output?` I don't think so.

Comment: your hint helped me a lot already, but there still seems to be missing something (I've added a "update" section describing my problem). Is there something else you know which affects the calculation of resulting PIDs from calls of `clone` or `clone3`?